# How to have a results class in LINQ connect to 3 tables?

Tags: c#, linq, statistics

Here is my situation: I have 2 stored procedures I used to call my data:

- Hits
- Uniques

They both return the same results but from different tables. The situation is I am using a method called `TargetRate()` and instead of putting it in both class partials I would like to have a result type be a class where I can share the TargetRate function and other functions with both those without having to rewrite the function when I make changes.

E.g.

- HitsProcedure
- UniquesProcedure
- = Return type Stat

I would like to use the object Stat output my results as well as use the shared methods. Can someone explain how I would do this?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to re-explain this - I've read it twice and both times it did not make sense.

Comment: How do you return the same results but from different tables?  At the very least, the return value is going to be of a different type (i.e., the LINQ-to-SQL DBML type associated with that particular table).

Comment: Hi sorry guys, I want to share methods between multiple result types or have one result type with methods I can apply to my data.

Comment: @Darren - Even after the update I am not understanding what you want :( how about including sample data, or expected results?  What do you mean without having to rewrite the function?  Just pass the table name to your sproc if that is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
public abstract class Stats
{
    // put your fields here
    public bool Exists { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public Frob Foo { get; set; }

    public abstract void Fill();
}

public class UniquesProcedureStats : Stats
{
    public override void Fill()
    {
        // make call to call Uniques
        this.Exists = false;
        this.Count = 1
    }
}

public class HitsProcedureStats : Stats
{
    public override void Fill()
    {
        // make call to call HitsProcedure
        this.Exists = true;
        this.Foo = new Frob();
    }
}
```

Or maybe like this:

```
public abstract class Stats
{
    // put your fields here
    public bool Exists { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public Frob Foo { get; set; }

    public abstract void Fill(string procedureName)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Get your own connection string");
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = procedureName; // your query may be more complicated than this?
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            reader.Read();
            this.Count = (int)reader["Count"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I get the class that is calling the abstract class's properties?

Comment: Would they have to be method arguments?

Comment: @Darren I don't think you need to know which class? You're going to have to provide additional information as to what it is you really want.

Comment: Thanks I used an abstract class.